# Facebook PHP SDK, when calling Graph API with 'privacy' => custom unexpected behavior?

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to post something to my own feed via facebook's php SDK with privacy => custom. The message appears on my feed just fine, it also indicates the users I had selected just fine. But the users I had selected are not able to see the post.

Here's what I am working with:

```
    try {
        $privacy = array(
            'value'     => 'CUSTOM',
            'allow'     => $users_string
        );
        $statusUpdate = $this->facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=> $content, 'privacy'=> json_encode($privacy)));
        return "true";
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        return json_encode($e->getMessage());
    }
```

As mentioned, I can see the post come up in my feed, and I can see what users are allowed to view the post. But when I view my own wall as one of those users, the post doesn't show up.

I think I have narrowed down the problem to somehow incorrect $users_string. It's basically json object that I receive and transform into a string using this code:

```
    $users_string;
    for ($i=0; $i < count($users); $i++) 
    { 
        if($i == 0)
        {
            $users_string = $users[$i];
        }
        else
        {
            $users_string = $users_string . ", " . $users[$i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think I narrowed down the problem to somehow incorrect $users_string, I'll edit the post to include the code

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem has gone away after replacing $users_string with an actual id of a user, submitting a post, and then switching back to $users_string. Weird.